# pointwise and uniform convergence of a succession of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have this succession of functions : $f_n(x)={e^{-nx}\arctan(n^{|x|})\over{1+e^{-nx}}}$.

I have pointwise convergence to the function $f(x)= \pi/2$ if $x<0$; $\pi/8$ if $x=0$ and $0$ if $x>0$?

and for the uniform convergence?

Answer (score 0):

If $x>0$ then
$$
0\le f_n(x)\le\frac{\pi}{2}\,e^{-nx}.
$$
The limit function is discontinuous and each $f_n$ is continuous. This should tell you something about uniform convergence.

Comment: sup $f_n(x)\le $sup $\pi/2 e^{-nx}=\pi/2$ in $(0,+\infty)$ so i don't have uniform convergence in $(0,+\infty)$. I consider the interval $[a,+\infty), a>0$ and here i have uniform convergence.

Comment: I have uniform convergence if x<0?

Comment: There is uniform convergence on $(-\infty,a]$ for $a<0$.